# zsh: command not found: conda

Tags: conda

I can't found my conda. I already have tried the solution from normal answer, but it didn't work out.

### This is my anaconda path : /Users/ShuanWu/Documents/anaconda

### from .zshrc

```
export PATH="/Users/ShuanWu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/usr/texbin"

export PATH="$PATH:/Users/ShuanWu/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/Dz/.rvm/bin"
```

Comment: Don't use a screenshot; please copy-paste your output into your question.

Comment: Please add in which directory you installed conda? Where is the executable located?

Comment: @Evert This is my anaconda path :  /Users/ShuanWu/Documents/anaconda

Comment: Please copy-paste your output *into* your question, not as a comment.

Comment: @Evert Just like the title. -> conda install anything , show zsh: command not found: conda

Comment: A question should be comprehensible without needing the title, and certainly without needing comments. Put the relevant things *in* your question, and replace the screenshot with actual text.

Comment: @Evert Do you want to help me fix the question?

Comment: You can simple [edit] your question with my suggestions.

Comment: @Evert OK, I changed it.

Comment: You say anaconda is found in `/Users/ShuanWu/Documents/anaconda`. Yet your `PATH` includes `/Users/ShuanWu/anaconda/bin`: the `Documents` subdirectory is missing.

Comment: @Evert Yep! It worked, thanks.